# difficulty calling a file='var.dat'

Tags: r, database, variables, hierarchical-bayesian

I have looked through the help files and have not found my answer.

I have a .dat file which lists variables and contains their data.

in the 'var.dat' file the first lines look like this:  (I've cut it down for ease of viewing)

```
"N" <- 55872
"Nc" <- 49
"g0" <- c(0, 0)
"G0" <- structure(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0.1), .Dim = c(2, 2))
"group" <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
"X" <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
"y" <- c(10, 10, 10, 9, 4, 10, 10)
"var1" <- c(8.7, 3.7, 3.6, 3.1, 8.9)
"Tau" <- structure(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1), .Dim = c(3, 3))
```

Here is my question.

in the following line of code I need to reference the var.dat file.

How is this code calling the file?  Where do I need to save it so the code can access the file= function?  Do I need to load it first?

```
mod.dat<- cat(dump.format(list(
      N = nrow(X), Nc = length(group), g0 = c(0,0), G0 = 
      diag(2)*.1, group=grp, X=X, y = dat$dv, var=var[,2], Tau = 
      diag(3)*.1)), file="var.dat")
```

Thanks.

Comment: `dump.format`? I don't have that one in my base R.

Comment: `bayescount::dump.format` maybe? You probably have to provide information about all the packages you've loaded from a fresh R session to make this code run. As Rich notes, this isn't a standard piece of code.

Comment: I use it all the time.  it's from package 'runjags'  i have never used it with file='' though....

Comment: @RichScriven it's in package 'runjags'

Comment: @thelatemail failed.jags() returns it is not able to fine the variables in that file.  I will keep trying.

Is there another way to get the file in the console?

Comment: The `var.dat` file just looks like a bunch of R objects being defined. You could probably just use `?source` to read it in.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for the suggestion.  I tried source() , and in the code:

    `code` Tau = diag(3)*.1)), source=nf.file)

and a few others....

for far still retuning mod.dat object as NULL